# Variant data-type formula error when defining new calculated column with IF

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in Power BI.

I am trying to create a new column with IF formula but resulting in an error. Please help.

[image]

Comment: You can try with change data type of your column "Terms of payment" as Text first.

Comment: Does the error go away if you add `+0` to the second `Net due date`?

Answer (score 0):

**[Net Due Date]** column is in Text format, change it to Date Format or update the formula like below.

```
dsad = IF('ARIBA RAW'[Terms of Payment]="Z003",DATEVALUE('ARIBA RAW'[Net due Date])+2,DATEVALUE('ARIBA RAW'[Net due Date]))
```